# MUI Input field that only accepts letters, numbers, and dashes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, input, material-ui

How could I restrict a MUI input field to only accept letters, numbers, and dashes? So spaces and and symbols (*&^%$#@!,.<>{}[]) would be excluded.

More specifically, I'd like to allow anything that wouldn't cause a URL to crash, i.e. https://mywebsite.com/user-generated-string-here123.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass a handler to `onKeyDown` and check for the pressed key. Exclude if the pressed key is other than alphabet, number, or dash.

```
const ALPHA_NUMERIC_DASH_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/;
```

```
<TextField
  onKeyDown={(event) => {
    if (!ALPHA_NUMERIC_DASH_REGEX.test(event.key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }}
/>
```

Alternatively, for controlled components, you can validate in `onChange` handler and update the state based on the value. This will also validate the value that is pasted in the text field and ignore if the condition doesn't pass.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
```

```
<TextField
  value={value}
  onChange={(event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (value !== "" && !ALPHA_NUMERIC_DASH_REGEX.test(value)) {
      return;
    }
    setValue(value);
  }}
/>
```

Here's the link to the [working demo in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-alpha-numeric-and-dash-textfield-zrj3c8).